# parsing xml with namespace in groovy

Tags: xml, groovy, xml-parsing, xml-namespaces

I have the following xml:

```
<profile:monitoringProfile xmlns:profile="http://xyz">
   <profile:eventSource profile:eventSourceAddress="IN.terminal.out" profile:enabled="true">
      <profile:eventPointDataQuery>  
   </profile:eventSource>
   <profile:eventSource profile:eventSourceAddress="OUT.terminal.in" profile:enabled="true">
      <profile:eventPointDataQuery>
   </profile:eventSource>
</profile:monitoringProfile>
```

I want to update the attribute value in this xml
want to change from

```
<profile:eventSource profile:eventSourceAddress="IN.terminal.out" profile:enabled="**true**">
```

to

```
<profile:eventSource profile:eventSourceAddress="IN.terminal.out" profile:enabled="**false**">
```

have written following code in groovy:

```
def monitorPropsKey=[IN.terminal.out, OUT.terminal.in]
def monitorPropsValue=[false, false]

File monitorxml = new File("test.xml")
def prof = new groovy.xml.Namespace("http://xyz",'profile')

def monitorParseXml = new XmlParser().parse(monitorxml)

def arrayLength = monitorPropsKey.size() - 1

for (int i=0; i<=arrayLength; i++) {
 
        monitorParseXml.prof.eventSource[i].each {
                    if(it.prof.@eventSourceAddress.text() == "${monitorPropsKey[i]}") {
                                it.prof.@enabled = "${monitorPropsValue[i]}"
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

its still giving the orignal xml , it does not update the xml. Please help

Answer (score 0):

to access qualified names (names with namespace) you have to use accessor:

`xml[NAMESPACE.NAME]` to access xml element

and `xml.attributes()[NAMESPACE.NAME]` to access attribute

```groovy
def xmlstr = '''
<profile:monitoringProfile xmlns:profile="http://xyz">
   <profile:eventSource profile:eventSourceAddress="IN.terminal.out" profile:enabled="true">
      <profile:eventPointDataQuery/>
   </profile:eventSource>
   <profile:eventSource profile:eventSourceAddress="OUT.terminal.in" profile:enabled="true">
      <profile:eventPointDataQuery/>
   </profile:eventSource>
</profile:monitoringProfile>
'''

def monitorPropsKey=['IN.terminal.out', 'OUT.terminal.in']
def monitorPropsValue=[false, false]

def prof = new groovy.xml.Namespace("http://xyz")
def monitorParseXml = new XmlParser().parseText(xmlstr)

for (int i=0; i<monitorPropsKey.size(); i++) {
    def e = monitorParseXml[prof.eventSource].find{ it.attributes()[prof.eventSourceAddress]==monitorPropsKey[i] }
    if(e)e.attributes()[prof.enabled]=monitorPropsValue[i]
    else println "key '${monitorPropsKey[i]}' not found"
}

println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(monitorParseXml)
```